# I sent money via Western Union for a friend and it has been flagged

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer

I sent money via Western Union for a friend and it has been flagged. I don’t what it was for. Now he’s angry it did not go through. He's threatening my son and me. What should I do?  I’m supposed to call Western Union. I’m worried. Should I contact the police or the FBI?

Comment: "threatening my son and me" doesn't sound like a friend. Is this a person you met online? Somebody you actually know? Could be a scam...

Comment: What do you mean you sent money "for" a friend? Did you send money to them or did they give you money to send to someone else?

Comment: Also, have you ever met this person in real life?

Comment: He might have taken it and claim he never got it. This screams scam so loudly.

Comment: "I don’t what it was for" What does "it" refer to? Does it refer to the wire transfer, or the flagging?

Answer (score 17):

If your "friend" is threatening your son and you, you go straight to the police.

If this "friend" is not someone who you have known in person for a long time, then it is quite possible and even likely that the "sending money *for your friend*" is some kind of scam. So: Call the police, and call Western Union.

If Western Union "flagged" this transaction, that means the transaction followed a pattern that in their experience is some scam.